# Create a correlation data.frame based on text.values from another data.frame in R?

Tags: r

**Background:**  I have a data.frame with text.values ranging from A to F, based on this data I want to compute the correlation data.frame in between the different companies by using this formula (example between company Aa & Cc):

Count the number of times Aa & Cc move together, here 3 times and divide by the number of periods, here 4. Then create a data.frame with the different correlations. I have no clue of how to start this.. some insight would be much appreciated.

**I have the following values in data.frame "databasis"**

```
       company    sector    lastmarketcap   X200202 X200203 X200204 X200205       
    1   Aa           B          18            A        D      E        B
    2   Bb           A          4571          F        C      D        B
    3   Cc           E          122           A        D      E        E 
    4   Dd           Z          239           B        C      E        C
```

**Code for this table:**

```
company <- c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd") 
sector <- c("B", "A", "E", "Z") 
lastmarketcap <- c(18, 4571, 122, 239) 
X200202 <- c("A", "D", "E", "B") 
X200203 <- c("F", "C", "D", "B") 
X200204 <- c("A", "D", "E", "E") 
X200205 <- c("B", "C", "E", "C") 

databasis <- data.frame(company, sector, lastmarketcap, X200202, X200203, X200204, X200205)
```

**Output**

```
          lastmarketcap  company Aa     Bb     Cc      Dd
       1       18          Aa    1     0.25   0.75    0.25
       2       4571        Bb    0.25    1      0     0.25
       3       122         Cc    0.75    0      1     0.25 
       4       239         Dd    0.25  0.25    0.25     1
```

Thank you in advance fellows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using base R:

```
dat=as.data.frame(t(subset(databasis,select = -(2:3))),stringsAsFactors = F)
m= combn(dat,2,function(x)sum(Reduce("==",x)))/4
mat=diag(4)
mat[lower.tri(mat)]=m
mat[upper.tri(mat)]=t(mat)[upper.tri(mat)]
mat


    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1.00 0.25 0.75 0.25
[2,] 0.25 1.00 0.00 0.25
[3,] 0.75 0.00 1.00 0.25
[4,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 1.00
```

data:

```
databasis=read.table(text="    company    sector    lastmarketcap   X200202 X200203 X200204 X200205       
    1   Aa           B          18            A        D      E        B
                     2   Bb           A          4571          F        C      D        B
                     3   Cc           E          122           A        D      E        E 
                     4   Dd           Z          239           B        C      E        C")
```

You can also do:

```
dat=as.data.frame(t(subset(databasis,select = -(2:3))),stringsAsFactors = F)
m= combn(dat,2,function(x)sum(x[[1]]==x[[2]])/4)
n=combn(company,2,paste,collapse=" ")
n1=sub("(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)","\\2 \\1",n)
prob=xtabs(V3~V1+V2,read.table(text=c(paste(n,m),paste(n1,m),
                                paste(company,company,1))))
cbind(databasis[1:2],as.data.frame.matrix(prob))
 company sector   Aa   Bb   Cc   Dd
1      Aa      B 1.00 0.25 0.75 0.25
2      Bb      A 0.25 1.00 0.00 0.25
3      Cc      E 0.75 0.00 1.00 0.25
4      Dd      Z 0.25 0.25 0.25 1.00
```

Comment: Hello the final output does not match... neither the transpose used in the first code, but thanks for the help

Comment: When the data frame is transposed, values with letters from A-F do stay in the same position

Comment: I see why they don't match. I do have 0.5 instead of 0.25. That is a quick fix

Comment: Question: If I want it to make it dynamic,  without knowing the number of companies and dates I would have in each table, how would I proceed? Thanks a lot again for your help :)

Comment: where there is 4 replace with `(nrow(dat)-1)`

Comment: Thank you ! And so How do you fix the transpose problem of the values?

Comment: I re-read in your data, I realized the way you wrote them is not the way its supposed to be. Look at the data I have used

Comment: True, sorry for that !

Comment: I am tryng to run it on a bigger set... and I keep getting this error: Error in combn("Company.Name", 2, paste, collapse = " ") : n < m

Comment: you need to have `combn(data$companyName,2,...)` Ensure You get that vector correctly. Try the first one

Comment: look at how my `dat` looks like

Comment: first code worked fine, the problem is it takes into account NaN ( from large tables) values for the correlation when it should not..